# How can I get Azure application settings locally?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

I'm attempting to integrate SendGrid with my application, which is hosted on Azure.

One of the instructions is to store the API key as an application setting in Azure, which I have done.

I'm trying to test locally, and when I try and get that setting, it's coming back as `null`:

```
var apiKey = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SENDGRID_APIKEY");
```

I figured maybe it needed to be in my web.config, so I added it there, and it still comes back as `null`.

Is there a way to get those settings locally? Or do I need to somehow determine that I'm running locally, and use a different method instead of `GetEnvironmentVariable()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, you want to place your SendGrid API key in the  section of your web.config file. It will look something along the lines of:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    ... other web.config settings ....
    <appSettings>
        <add key="SendGridAPIKey" value="[Your key goes here]" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

You can retrieve this value with the following line of code:

```
string apiKey = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SendGridAPIKey"];
```

This will work both locally and within your Azure Web App.

Comment: Thanks Rob - but when I deploy my changes to the site that's hosted in Azure, I'd like to get the API key from Azure's application settings, not the web.config (in case I want it to be different locally than in my Azure environment). How can I do that?

Comment: Hi Steven, the code above will actually retrieve what's in the Azure Web App Application Settings. Azure Web App Application Settings take precedence and overwrite whatever is specified in your deployed web.config file. So, if I had an appSetting of SendGridAPIKey in the web.config called "foo", and an application setting in the Web App called SendGridAPIKey with a value of "bar", the code above will return "bar" to my application because Web App Application Settings take precedence. I actually prefer specifying production settings in Web App settings instead of relying on web.config transform